# data json in python

Tags: python, json

I have the Json below where I want to retrieve the value of the Line field which in this example is "component = '1.37.1-number-1234-SNAPSHOT'" if it has the word SNAPSHOT in the value.

I'm trying this in python but I'm having trouble accessing this part of Json.

If you can give some light at the end of the tunnel I would appreciate it

```
"diffs":[
      {
         "source":"None",
         "destination":{
            "components":[
               "abc"
            ],
            "parent":"",
            "name":"abc",
            "toString":"abc"
         },
         "hunks":[
            
         ],
         "truncated":false
      },
      {
         "source":{
            "components":[
               "abcd"
            ],
            "parent":"",
            "name":"abcd",
            "extension":"txt",
            "toString":"abcd"
         },
         "destination":"None",
         "hunks":[
            {
               "sourceLine":1,
               "sourceSpan":2,
               "destinationLine":0,
               "destinationSpan":0,
               "segments":[
                  {
                     "type":"REMOVED",
                     "lines":[
                        {
                           "source":1,
                           "destination":0,
                           "line":"alteração 2",
                           "truncated":false
                        },
                        {
                           "source":2,
                           "destination":0,
                           "line":"",
                           "truncated":false
                        }
                     ],
                     "truncated":false
                  }
               ],
               "truncated":false
            }
         ],
         "truncated":false
      },
      {
         "source":"None",
         "destination":{
            "components":[
               "build.gradle"
            ],
            "parent":"",
            "name":"build.gradle",
            "extension":"gradle",
            "toString":"build.gradle"
         },
         "hunks":[
            {
               "sourceLine":0,
               "sourceSpan":0,
               "destinationLine":1,
               "destinationSpan":615,
               "segments":[
                  {
                     "type":"ADDED",
                     "lines":[
                        {
                           "source":0,
                           "destination":18,
                           "line":"        componente = '1.37.1-number-1234-SNAPSHOT'",
                           "truncated":false
                        },
```

Comment: Check this library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: You `json` data is not valid. Then you can use python `json` library to reach required key

Comment: There is no light at the end of the proverbial tunnel, unfortunately. You'll have to `json.loads` the data and traverse down the path until you reach the field which you want the value of.

Comment: This is just a part of json, it's not complete